# I want to call {{$barang->stock}} in php condition and return text value

Tags: php, html, laravel, routes

`{{$barang->stock}}` this is code to view my database value. I wanna use it for a condition -

> "if ({{$barang->stock}} >= 1; "Ready Stock"; "Stock Empty") "

```
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Jacket Color</th>
                                <th>Stock</th>
                                <th>Product Sales</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>Product Status</th>
                                <th>Create At</th>
                                <th>Setting</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach($barang as $barang)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$barang->id}}</td>
                                <td>{{$barang->color}}</td>
                                <td>{{$barang->stock}}</td>
                                <td>{{$barang->sales}}</td>
                                <td>Rp {{$barang->price}}</td>
                                <td>{{if ($barang->stock >= 1)}}</td>
                                <td>{{$barang->created_at}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button href="{{ route('barang.edit',$barang->id)}}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit" class="pd-setting-ed"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                    <form action="{{ route('barang.destroy', $barang->id)}}" method="post">
                                        @csrf
                                        @method('DELETE')
                                        <button data-toggle="tooltip" title="Trash" class="pd-setting-ed"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        <tbody>
                    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td><button class="pd-setting {{ $barang->stock >= 1 ? 'ready-stock' : 'stock-empty' }}">{{ $barang->stock >= 1 ? 'Ready Stock' : 'Stock Empty' }}</button></td>
```

Comment: then if I have this line of code and I wanna make a conndition if true class = pd-setting if false = ds-setting

`<td><button class="pd-setting">{{($barang->stock >= 1 ? 'Ready Stock' : 'Stock Empty')}}</button></td>`

Comment: `<td><button class="pd-setting">{{$barang->stock >= 1 ? 'Ready Stock' : 'Stock Empty'}}</button></td>`

yeah I mean if true class = pd-setting + "Ready Stock" text if false class = ds-setting + "Stock Empty" text

Comment: Please try is it works and let me know- `<td><button class="pd-setting  {!! $barang->stock >= 1 ? 'Ready Stock' : 'Stock Empty' !!}">{{ $barang->stock >= 1 ? 'Ready Stock' : 'Stock Empty' }}</button></td>`

Comment: If you want to use also as class name. please not declare as separeted word. Try like this - `<td><button class="pd-setting {{ ($barang->stock >= 1) ? 'ReadyStock' : 'StockEmpty' }}">{{ $barang->stock >= 1 ? 'Ready Stock' : 'Stock Empty' }}</button></td>`

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope it should work. If not, please share the error if any.